# Javascript and React working in Intllije, but it is an java ide so how?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, intellij-idea

I just ran my JavaScript and react code inside the IntelliJ (An java IDE) and it ran perfectly can anyone explain me this

Comment: Have you an actual question ? Why are you confused that your code could be run ?? This doesn't looks like a reproducible "problem" ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality of IntelliJ IDEA could be extended to the most of IDEs of JetBrains (WebStrom, PhpStorm, Goland etc) by installing the appropriate plugins. So, installing JavaScript plugin allows you  to tun JavaScript inside IntelliJ IDEA